# Jquery animation and element binding paradox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to animate a div when the user clicks on it so that the current "main" div moves out of the field of view and another div moves into the window so that the user can see more details about the thing they clicked on.

The problem that I'm facing is that the button that I have implemented to take the user back to the main div cannot be bound to (.click). The code is shown below:

```
$(".notification").click(function() {
    $("#latestUpdates").hide("slide", { direction: "left", easing: "linear" }, 1000);

    $("#mainContainer").append('<div id="notification-details"></div>');
    $("#notification-details").hide();
    $("#notification-details").append('<a href="#" id="close-notification-details">Close</a>');
    $("#notification-details").show("slide", { direction: "right", easing: "linear" }, 1000);

    $("#close-notification-details").click(function() {
        $("#latestUpdates").show("slide", { direction: "left", easing: "linear" }, 1000);
        $("#notification-details").hide();
    });
});
```

when I click the close button in `#notification-details` nothing happens, and when I retype the code that re-binds to the close button into the FireBug console, it seems to work, I have a feeling the issue may be with jQuery binding to the element before it has completed the effect.

Thanks in advance,
RayQuang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use live to map click event

```
 $("#close-notification-details").live('click',function() {
        $("#latestUpdates").show("slide", { direction: "left", easing: "linear" }, 1000);
        $("#notification-details").hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

the source of the problem could be two things:

- Your JS ins executed before the DOM is interpreted by the browser. To make sure it is you can do two things: wrap your code with a document ready ( `$(function(){ /* your code*/ })`). Or place your code at the end of your html (just before the closing body tag)
- The second problem could be that your div is added to the dom by JS after your code is executed. You can solve this problem by using `$("a.yourlink").live("click", function(){ /* yourfunction */})`. This binds the click on every new element that is added to the DOM that has this ID.
- If none of this helps. Add a console.log("something") or alert("something") on top of your click function and see if it triggers. If not you know that the click event was not binded if it does something inside your click function does not work. The best thing to do then is to console.log() every single element that you are manipulating inside the click function to see it returns something...